# Summarize rows grouped by ID and preserve other, non-grouping variables

Tags: r, plyr

I have a data frame with entries such as

```
     GN      Datum     Land Wert
1 11747 2012-01-04 Thailand 7616
2 11747 2012-01-04 Thailand 6241
3 11747 2012-01-04 Thailand 1174
4 11747 2012-01-04 Thailand 2156
```

GN is the ID. But in this case, all four entries have the same ID. What I want is to summarize "Wert", so that in the end I have:

```
     GN      Datum     Land Wert
1 11747 2012-01-04 Thailand 17187
```

How can I do this? I know I should probably use `plyr` package or `apply` or something, but I am pretty clueless where to start.

Secondly, let's say there are more variables in the data frame, and I don't want to group by them or summarize them, I just want to take their value - assuming they all have the same value in each group. How do I preserve those?

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(GN, Datum,Land) %>% summarise(Wert=sum(Wert))` or using `base R` `aggregate(Wert~., df, FUN=sum)`

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know how to correctly use the `summarise` function.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, It may be a duplicate but based on the OP's comment under my answer, it's not a duplicate of the question you linked to..

Comment: @docendodiscimus I don't see any comment under your answer except akruns

Comment: I've reopened, though I think you should try to include *all* the information in the first place rather than using `zoo::rolledit` every minute or too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R you can do:

```
aggregate(Wert ~ ., df, sum)
#     GN      Datum     Land  Wert
#1 11747 2012-01-04 Thailand 17187
```

If you want to preserve other columns you have in your data, you can for example do (using dplyr):

```
df %>% group_by(GN, Datum, Land) %>% mutate(Wert = sum(Wert)) %>% slice(1)
#     GN      Datum     Land  Wert
#1 11747 2012-01-04 Thailand 17187
```

This will keep other columns and only leave the first row of each group of GN, Datum, Land.